# Azure managed service DDOS protection

Tags: azure, signalr, ddos, azure-ddos

I am working on project hosted in Azure, and that project uses Azure services under the hood, such as Device Provisioning Service and SignalR.
So, question is quite simple - how to mitigate DDOS attacks to Azure SignalR and Device Provisioning Service?
Azure provide DDOS protection service, but it's not support these services.

Comment: did you check Application Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft edge network provides DDOS protection against cloud services, DDOS protection as a service is available for network-based resources on virtual networks rather than those that are classed as platform-as-a-service.

Comment: "The Microsoft edge network provides DDOS protection against cloud services"
Could you please be so kind and point me to any mentions or links?
The only place i have found some mentions - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/ddos-protection/, but it's not enough to get idea how it works, no details.

Comment: Sure, you’ll find all compliance details on the Trust Center... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trust-center/product-overview